# Вызов производного метода из базового класса

Tags: c#

Есть класс, от него наследуется другой класс. Нужно чтобы из базового класса, в зависимости от переданного обьекта, вызывался метод переданного объекта. Пробую делать так:

```
public class Modules
{
    public static List<Modules> ListModule = new List<Modules>();
    public static void RunModule(params Modules[] vkm)
    {
        for(int i =0;i<vkm.Length;i++)
        {
            if(ListModule.Contains(vkm[i]))
                if (!vkm[i].Active)
                {
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                    {
                        await vkm[i].StartModule(new MessageSendParams());
                    },
                   TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
                }

        }
    }
    public virtual async Task<string> StartModule(MessageSendParams MSP)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        Console.WriteLine("не то");
        return "1";
    }
}


public class LSListModule : VkModules
{
    override public async Task<string> StartModule(MessageSendParams MSP)
    {
        if (!Active)
        {
            Active = true;
            //* .... *//                
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

В `RunModule` передаю производный класс, до `StartModule` доходит, но после него ничего не происходит. Не вызывает ни базовый метод, ни производный. Нужно, соответвенно, чтобы в данном случае был вызван метод производного класса.

Comment: Замыкание захватывает переменные, а не их значения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена следующим образом:

```
public static void RunModule(params Modules[] vkm)
{
    for(int i =0;i<vkm.Length;i++)
    {
        var _vkm = vkm[i];
        if(ListModule.Contains(_vkm))
            if (!_vkm.Active)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                {
                    await _vkm.StartModule(new MessageSendParams());
                },
               TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
            }
    }
}
```